Emacs is saying "wrong type argument: lisp:" for all the packages I am trying to install
I am trying to install and configure emacs and running into trouble because even though I have downloaded and installed the packages, it can't seem to find them when it loads up. I am getting this error:
Wrong type argument: listp, C:/directorypath/Pandoc/pandoc
Here is the code in my init.el:
(custom-set-variables
 (setq markdown-command "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc.exe")
 (setq ag-executable "G:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/ag.el-master/ag.el-master/ag.el")
 (setq find-program "G:/emacs-extensions/findutilsemacs/findutils-4.2.30-5-w64-bin/bin/find.exe")
 (add-to-list 'load-path "G:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/ag.el-master/ag.el-master/ag.el")
 (require 'ag)

 ;;Hunspell
 (setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
 (setq ispell-hunspell-dict-paths-alist
       '(("en_GB" "c:/hunspell/en_GB.aff")))
 (setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_GB")
 (setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
       '(("en_GB" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8)))
 (flyspell-mode 1)
 
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(exec-path
   '("c:/Python312/Scripts/" "C:/Python312/" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath" "C:/Python310/Scripts/" "C:/Python310/" "C:/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot/bin" "C:/Windows/system32" "C:/Windows" "C:/Windows/System32/Wbem" "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/" "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/" "C:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common" "C:/Program Files/dotnet/" "C:/Program Files/Git/cmd" "C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin" "C:/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin" "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin" "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/" "C:/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/" "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/" "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/" "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR" "C:/Program Files/PuTTY/" "C:/Program Files/nodejs/" "G:/emacs-extensions/" "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps" "C:/Users/myName/.dotnet/tools" "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin" "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Programs/Azure Data Studio/bin" "C:/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin" "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin" "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Roaming/npm" "g:/emacs-29.3/libexec/emacs/29.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32" "G:/emacs-extensions/findutilsemacs/findutils-4.2.30-5-w64-bin/bin" "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Pandoc/" "G:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/ag.el-master/ag.el/master/" "G:/emacs-extensions/hunspell/")))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )```


I have been trying to edit the directory paths but it isn't helping.

Edit: I moved the setq and hunspell lines out of custom set variables and now it isn't throwing any errors but it is still not doing anything. It says [no match] when I try to use the commands.


It's likely saying listp, not lisp. Bisect your init file, to find the culprit. Start Emacs with  emacs -Q no init file to test.

well I have moved the code around a lot and it is definitely the require 'ag line that gives me the error. I don't get errors if I move the code outside of those blocks but it also doesn't seem to do anything? I am trying to fix the file paths but they seem correct...

You've corrupted your custom-set-variables form:
(custom-set-variables

;;;;;;;; None of this (vvvvv) should be here!

 (setq markdown-command "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc.exe")
 (setq ag-executable "G:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/ag.el-master/ag.el-master/ag.el")
 (setq find-program "G:/emacs-extensions/findutilsemacs/findutils-4.2.30-5-w64-bin/bin/find.exe")
 (add-to-list 'load-path "G:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/ag.el-master/ag.el-master/ag.el")
 (require 'ag)

 ;;Hunspell
 (setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
 (setq ispell-hunspell-dict-paths-alist
       '(("en_GB" "c:/hunspell/en_GB.aff")))
 (setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_GB")
 (setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
       '(("en_GB" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8)))
 (flyspell-mode 1)
 
;;;;;;;; None of this (^^^^^) should be here!


 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(exec-path
   '(...)))

As it tells you in those comments:

;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.


Best to leave it alone completely.

I sent this to the other person who commented but I can make it so it doesn't have an error by moving the code out but then the code doesn't seem to read anything, and if I leave "(require 'ag)" uncommented then it throws an error saying it can't find ag

In that case the directory in which ag.el lives is not present in your C-h v load-path, and you need to deal to that before calling require.  Note that if you install things using the package manager, it will update your load-path automatically.  (If you did install it that way but you're using Emacs 26 or earlier, then you'd want to call (package-initialize) in your init file before trying to require any of them.)

Well there's your problem: (add-to-list 'load-path "G:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/ag.el-master/ag.el-master/ag.el") -- load-path is for directories containing lisp files, not for the lisp files themselves.

currently I am using emacs 29-3.
I have both G:/emacs-extensions/ag.el-master/ag.el-master
and also g:/emacs-extensions/ag/ag/
both in my load path but I don't think I understand why I need both. I stopped trying to use chocolatey and I just have the files installed I think

You only need the directory which contains the ag.el elisp file.  If there's no elisp in a directory, there's no reason for it to be in load-path.  If you have more than one ag.el file, that's probably a mistake (and Emacs will just use the first one it finds).

The documentation says that I need both ag and ag.el and I don't know why or how to set up the two files: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xWAaews8uv95HBCItVjIhK-6cueFJyWqM88QyoLuxk8/edit

I don't know much about Windows and I don't use ag, but... ag is a separate program, independent of Emacs.  ag.el is an Emacs Lisp library for integrating ag with Emacs.  You undoubtedly want to set ag-executable to the path to the executable program ag (or on Windows maybe it's named ag.exe), and your Emacs load-path needs to contain the path to the directory which contains ag.el.

Your load path is not a path - it looks like some strange combination of filenames.
But beyond that try using a package manager to install ag instead of doing it manually.

The tutorial I was following did not tell me to use a package manager and I am not sure how to do that. Do you have a tutorial you can link?

C-h i g (emacs)Packages.  It looks like you'll need to add MELPA to your list of package archives before you can install ag from there.

For clarity, I am referring there to the Emacs ag ELPA package -- the thing which provides the ag.el file -- as opposed to the ag program itself, which you'll have installed from somewhere else (potentially also using some kind of package manager, but certainly not the Emacs one).
